# Cancelling previous api requests created by ng-change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a search box attached to function in the angular controller to call a webservice to get a list of people:

```
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">Find Person</div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ng-change="vm.getPeople()" ng-model="vm.searchTxt" ng-model-options="{debounce: 500}"/>
        </div>
```

it has a debounce  to not fire off too many calls.

The function looks like this:

```
    function getPeople() {

        vm.spinner = true;

        peopleClient
            .get({
                GenSearchTerm: vm.searchTxt
            })
            .success(function (data) {
                vm.spinner = false;
                vm.searchResult = data.results;
            })
            .error(function (err) {
                vm.spinner = false;
                log.debug(err);
                err;
            });
    }
```

This works as expected, but with a problem. If I enter a very loose term that returns many result, then a very specific one that returns, say, 1 result (i.e. 'a' then 'Angela Smith') the data will come back for the specific term first, then be replaced when the callback is executed for the general term (which was first but took longer on the server side. Yes, the server side calls are too slow and I will look at fixing it there, but I would also like to handle it better client side.

So, how can I stop/cancel any in-flight requests created by this function if I know that a later call supersedes them?

**Edit:**

Awesome, this got me to a good point, and there are good examples of use of timeout. Wanted to see if anybody could tell me if this simple addition would be problematic. It works functionally, but not sure I am handling the promise resolve well.

```
function getPeople() {

    vm.spinner = true;


    //check for existing 
    if (vm.searchPromise) {
        //cancel the existing call 
        vm.searchPromise.resolve(); 
    }
    vm.searchPromise = $q.defer();

    peopleClient
        .get({
            GenSearchTerm: vm.searchTxt
        }, vm.searchPromise)
        .success(function (data) {
            vm.spinner = false;
            vm.searchResult = data.results;
        })
        .error(function (err) {
            vm.spinner = false;
            log.debug(err);
            err;
        });

}
```

then in the peopleClient:

```
    function get(params, deferred) {
        return $http.get(url + 'people', {
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_token
            },
            params: params,
            timeout: deferred.promise
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using restangular, you can use `timeout : requestCancelDeferred`:

```
var requestCancelDeferred = $q.defer();
```

Then when you need to cancel request:

```
requestCancelDeferred.resolve();
```

And your query:

```
return Restangular
    .one('homes')
    .withHttpConfig({ timeout : requestCancelDeferred.promise })
    .get(/*your query here*/);
```

---

Or using $http (with version 1.1.5+):

```
var requestCancelDeferred = $q.defer();
$http.get('/someUrl', {timeout: requestCancelDeferred.promise}).success(successCallback);
```

When you need to cancel:

```
requestCancelDeferred.resolve();
```

Comment: No, just using client services built with $http.

Comment: You were first in so I'll give it to you. Thanks for the help and the edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using service factory with $resource request you can do:

```
app.factory("peopleClient", function($http, $q) {
    var canceller = $q.defer();
    return $resource(url, options || {}, {
        'get': {
            method: 'GET',
            timeout: canceller.promise
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Sadly just using $http. Will look into that though.

Comment: So you can follow these examples: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/04/24/canceling-http-requests-in-angularjs.aspx

Comment: Cheers for the link. Between the 2 answers I got what I needed.